# Specify range of colors for density plot in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

# Generate fake data
x = np.random.normal(size=1000)
y = x * 3 + np.random.normal(size=1000)

# Calculate the point density
xy = np.vstack([x,y])
z = gaussian_kde(xy)(xy)

# Sort the points by density, so that the densest points are plotted last
idx = z.argsort()
x, y, z = x[idx], y[idx], z[idx]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=50, edgecolor='')
plt.show()
```

produces a graph like this:

[image]

How can I change the theme from red to, say, blue? Something like this:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.palplot(sns.color_palette("Blues"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign any color map to `scatter` plot as follows. [Here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) you will find all the existing colormaps in `matplotlib`.

The colormap you want is named `Blues`. You have to import `matplotlib.cm` to access the color maps and then pass the required color map as an argument to `cmap` in your scatter plot. Additionally, you can show the color bar for sake of interpretation of the colors. If you want to reverse a color map, just include `_r` at the end of that color map. For instance, `Blues_r` will reverse the map with the scale now going from blue (low) to white (high).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
import matplotlib.cm as cm

# Generate fake data
x = np.random.normal(size=1000)
y = x * 3 + np.random.normal(size=1000)

# Calculate the point density
xy = np.vstack([x,y])
z = gaussian_kde(xy)(xy)

# Sort the points by density, so that the densest points are plotted last
idx = z.argsort()
x, y, z = x[idx], y[idx], z[idx]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax_ = ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, cmap=cm.Blues, s=50, edgecolor='')
plt.colorbar(ax_)
```

[image]